# Big or Little Endian

Tags: code-golf

Write a program or function that outputs an `L` if run on a little endian architecture or a `B` if run on a big endian architecture. Lower case output `l` or `b` is also acceptable.

There is no input.

Scoring is code golf, so the code with the fewest bytes wins.

**Edit:** *As per the comments below, I am clarifying that the entry must be able to run on either architecture.*

*I believe that there is only one answer that this affects, and that answer has clearly indicated that this is the case.*

Comment: Does the little endian apply only to the memory, or every byte in the program source code as well?

Comment: The memory of the box. I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I think this is an interesting challenge (and it's way out of the norm) but it's going to be extremely hard to test it. Especially since most of the code will end up being extremely platform specific.

Comment: Yeah I think it'll be interesting because hopefully it's something that esolangs and golfing languages have a harder time with than 'normal' languages. I have a feeling that they won't be that hard to verify. Worst case they should be verifiable by hand

Comment: I'm guessing that if the language has the programmer define an endianness independently for every variable (and no endianness is imposed by the computer/interpreter/compiler/hardware), then it cannot compete here?

Comment: Hmm, I suppose it's impossible to write a program like this in assembly then, since it'll be architecture specific at that point anyway.

Comment: I guess an answer based on a specific machine code is forbidden? Otherwise `B0 4C C3`, which is `mov al, 'L' / ret` or `unsigned char f(){ return 'L'; }`, would be a valid x86 answer.

Comment: I think it should be clarified that the code must run on both little-endian and big-endian architectures, not just one.

Comment: If someone wants to test with a big endian architecture, here are some ways: [How to test your code on a machine with big-endian architecture?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2839087/995714), [Imitate/emulate a big-endian behavior in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3337896/995714). Another way may be running your app in your ARM phone in big endian mode

Comment: Speaking of ARM, does anyone know enough about ARM (or PPC) assembly to write an endianness test in it?

Comment: Bravo! for a code golf challenge in which general-purpose programming languages can be competitive.

Comment: @Random832: done with PPC, I hope I haven't messed up too much (I knew next to nothing about PPC until 2 hours ago =) ); I'll see if I manage to do ARM.

Answer (score 40):

## Python, 33 bytes

```py
import sys
exit(sys.byteorder[0])
```

`sys.byteorder` is either `'little'` or `'big'` (and for those of you who will read this sentence without looking at the code, `[0]` means take the first character).

Comment: The challenge says the output must be `L` and `B` (or the lowercase variant), not the entire word.

Comment: That's why it says `sys.byteorder[0]`, i.e. the first char of `byteorder`.

Answer (score 35):

## C, 26 bytes

```c
a=66<<24|76;f(){puts(&a);}
```

Assumes 32-bit `int` and ASCII characters.  Tested on amd64 (little-endian) and mips (big-endian).

## GCC, 23 bytes

```
00000000: 613d 2742 0000 4c27 3b66 2829 7b70 7574  a='B..L';f(){put
00000010: 7328 2661 293b 7d                        s(&a);}
```

Suggested by feersum.  The value of multi-character constants is implementation-dependent, but this seems to work in GCC.  Tested on the same architectures.

Comment: Shorter is `a='B\0\0L';` The `\0`s can be replaced with null bytes.

Comment: @feersum The endianness of multi-character constants seems to be implementation dependent. I wouldn't normally worry about that much in code golf, but this challenge is all about distinguishing between implementations.

Comment: Does this code currently work in something other than GCC?

Comment: @feersum I believe the `66<<24|76` solution should work on every standards-compliant C compiler (with 32-bit `int` and ASCII characters), but I don’t know how to easily access a big-endian C compiler other than GCC or clang.

Comment: Is there a standard for K&R style C? I didn't think something with missing types and implicit function definitions could be called standard-compliant.

Comment: @feersum [C89](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.txt) allows both.

Comment: Using xlc (VisualAge C++ Professional / C for AIX Compiler, Version 6) on an RS6000 running AIX 5.2 the 26 byte program successfully prints "B"

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman That wasn't the revision that didn't work. After downloading a virtual machine, I edited my answer and undeleted it, just after feersum had added his comment. I realized not only that it was too late, but that my fix was too similar to this answer, so I re-deleted it.

Comment: @Dennis Ah, whoops, thanks!

Answer (score 24):

## MATLAB / Octave, 24 bytes

```
[~,~,e]=computer;disp(e)
```

The [`computer`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/computer.html) function gives information about, well, the computer it's running on. The third output is endianness: `L` or `B` for little- or big-endian respectively.

[Try it on Ideone](http://ideone.com/FpfrEb).

Comment: what. This is somethign for stackoverflow, I didnt know this!

Answer (score 20):

## JavaScript ES6, 50 bytes

```js
_=>"BL"[new Int8Array(Int16Array.of(1).buffer)[0]]
```

I don’t know who decided it was a good idea for [TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) objects to expose the native endianness of the interpreter, but here we are.

Comment: WebGL people thought it was a good idea, to avoid having to convert endianness when passing to the GPU. Pretty much everyone else thought it stupid… :(

Answer (score 11):

## C, <s>36</s> 35 bytes

**1 byte thanks to @algmyr and @owacoder.**

```C
main(a){printf(*(char*)&a?"L":"B");}
main(a){putchar(66+10**(char*)&a);}
main(a){putchar("BL"[*(char*)&a]);}
```

- Version 1: [Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/uWicng)
- Version 2: [Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/OjpPrP)
- Version 3: [Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/DzmxIa)

Credits [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4181991/6211883).

Untested since I don't have a big-endian machine.

Comment: Does the C spec allow a one-argument `main` function?

Comment: @codesinchaos yes it does. It will be the number of command line arguments given. Usually here it is used to have a variable initiated to `1` because no input is given (and the program name always counts as the first argument)

Comment: @Liam: If anything other than 0 or 2 is allowed is implementation defined in C11.

Comment: I like how this could be broken by adding enough input arguments to either have a multiple of 255 or populate the top octet.

Comment: Also, if we really want things to break if there is input, we can save a byte with `main(a){putchar(66+10**(char*)&a);}`

Comment: Or `main(a){putchar("BL"[*(char*)&a]);}`.

Comment: @algmyr But the question clearly states: `There is no input.` So no command line arguments either

Comment: @CodesInChaos it's allowed and is used in many [code ofuscation contests](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15393441/995714)

Comment: @WorldSEnder I know, I just like volatile solutions.

Comment: I don't know a big-endian online compiler but you can use [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:ppcg48,options:'-O2',source:'%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0Aint+main(int+a,+char+**b)%0A%7B%0A++int+n+%3D+1%3B%0A++//+little+endian+if+true%0A++printf(*(char+*)%26n+%3D%3D+0+%3F+%22B%22+:+%22L%22)%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) with a big-endian compiler and see the optimized asm output if it prints directly L or B

Comment: [How to test your code on a machine with big-endian architecture?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2839087/995714), [Imitate/emulate a big-endian behavior in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3337896/995714)

Comment: If you mess with the call convention it goes down to 31: `main(char a){putchar("BL"[a]);}`.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, one-argument `main()` is not forbidden by the standard, but neither is it allowed.  Implementations are explicitly permitted to support such signatures, but strictly-conforming programs cannot rely on them.  In other words, the program given is not written in standard C.  It may, however, be written in the idiosyncratic extended dialect of one or more C implementations.

Comment: @AndreaBiondo That worked well...

Answer (score 8):

#### Mathematica, 22

```
{B,L}[[$ByteOrdering]]
```

This probably breaks some rule about not using a built-in function but I'm not really interested in rube goldberging an alternative.

Comment: Built-ins are fine (most answers are using them too)

Comment: And once again, Mathematica has a built-in!

Comment: I think this is a snippet, not a program or function, and you should add `&` to make it a function. (But there may be disagreement over what constitutes a “program”.)

Comment: @Anders I am not really familiar with the current standards for PCG (if I ever was) but IMHO one advantage of an interpreted language is that a snippet *is* a program.  This can be run in a stand-alone manner as much as any other program in *Mathematica*.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Note that a "program" in Mathematica refers to a standalone script (which requires explicit printing), whereas this answer uses the REPL.

Comment: @Legion I feel that this is a matter of opinion unless you can support your position with an authoritative reference.

Answer (score 8):

## C, 27

One byte longer, but here it is anyway:

```
f(){putchar(htons(19522));}
```

Comment: It worked fine, can you please explain it to me.

Comment: @ABcDexter the binary expansion of 19522 is `1001100 01000010` (space to separate bytes). Now if you take each byte, convert back to base 10 and check the ASCII table, you will see that this byte sequence is equivalent to `LB`. `htons` will [do its thing](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons), and `putchar` will only print the LSB. In big-endian systems, that will be `B`, in little-endian, `htons` will have flipped the bytes, so the LSB is `L`.

Comment: Replace `19522` with `'LB'` for compiler warnings and -1 byte.

Answer (score 8):

## PowerPC machine code - 20 bytes

PowerPC is bi-endian (the endianness can be set up at startup), so this code should conform to the challenge request of being able to run both on BE and LE machines. This is a function that *returns*<sup>1</sup> `'L'` or `'B'` depending on the endianness currently set.

As a function, AFAICT it conforms the SVR4 PowerPC ABI (used by Linux on ppc32), the PowerOpen ABI (used e.g. by AIX) and the OS X ABI. In particular, it relies just on the fact that GPR 0 is a volatile scratch register, and GPR 3 is used to return "small" values.

```
00000000 <get_endian>:
   0:   7c 00 00 a6     mfmsr   r0
   4:   54 03 0f fe     rlwinm  r3,r0,1,31,31
   8:   1c 63 00 0a     mulli   r3,r3,10
   c:   38 63 00 42     addi    r3,r3,66
  10:   4e 80 00 20     blr
```

Now, it goes like this:

- the [MSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_state_register) is read into GP register 0; the MSR contains at bit 31 the endianness settings (0 = big endian; 1 = little endian);
- `rlwinm` extracts just that bit: it takes the value in GPR0, **r**otates **l**eft by 1 place (so that now is in position 0) and **m**asks it with 1 (the mask generated by those 31,31<sup>2</sup>); the result is put into GP register 3;
- multiply the result by 10 and sum 66 (`'B'`) (10 is the difference between `'L'` and `'B'`)
- finally, return to the caller

---

#### Notes

1. yep, the question does ask to *print*, but it's not clear how I should print stuff in assembly expected to run unmodified on different operating systems. =)
2. for those interested, see the [rlwinm](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.alangref/idalangref_rlwinm_rlinm_rtlwrdimm_instrs.htm) documentation; knowing next to nothing about PowerPC, I found this kind of instructions extremely interesting.

   **2018 update**: Raymond Chen is publishing a series about the PowerPC architecture, you can find [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180810-00/?p=99465) his great post about `rlwinm` & friends.

Answer (score 7):

## Java 8, <s>96, 64</s> 52 bytes

```
()->(""+java.nio.ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).charAt(0);
```

A golf based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9431652). All credit goes to @LeakyNun and @AlanTuning. Java keeps the loosing streak.

96 bytes:

```
 char e(){return java.nio.ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(java.nio.ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)?'b':'l';}
```

64 bytes:

```
char e(){return(""+java.nio.ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).charAt(0);}
```

Untested b/c I don't have access to a big-endian machine.

Comment: `char e(){return(""+java.nio.ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).charAt(0);}`

Comment: `char e(){return(""+java.nio.Bits.byteOrder()).charAt(0);}`

Comment: @LeakyNun I don't see Bits in the Java API, and when I run it it gives me "Bits is not public in java.nio"

Comment: Oh, alright then.

Comment: 52 bytes if you use a lambda! `()->(""+java.nio.ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).charAt(0);`

Answer (score 6):

## Perl, <s>38</s> 36 bytes

```
say+(pack"L",1 eq pack"V",1)?"L":"B"
```

Works by packing a number in the system's default byte order and comparing it to a number packed in little-endian byte order.

Answer (score 6):

## (G)Forth, 24 bytes

```
here $4200004C , c@ emit
```

Assumes that cells are 32 bits (and that your Forth interpreter supports Gforth's [base prefixes](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Number-Conversion.html#fnd-2)).  It simply stores the number 0x4200004C in memory and then displays the byte at the low end.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP 5.6, <s>41</s> 31 bytes (thx to isertusernamehere)

`<?=unpack(S,"\x01\x00")[1]-1?B:L;`

## PHP 7, 41 bytes

`echo unpack('S',"\x01\x00")[1]-1?'B':'L';`

Idea stolen from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24785578/2496717

Comment: You can save *10 bytes*: `<?=unpack(S,"\x01\x00")[1]-1?B:L;`.

Answer (score 5):

## C#, <strike>60</strike> 52 bytes

C# is surprisingly competitive in this one.

```cs
char e=>System.BitConverter.IsLittleEndian?'L':'B';
```

Credits to Groo for the C#6 syntax.

60 bytes:

```cs
char e(){return System.BitConverter.IsLittleEndian?'L':'B';}
```

Comment: With C#6 syntax you can shorten it a bit: `char e=>System.BitConverter.IsLittleEndian?'L':'B';`, of course this (as well as the Java answer) doesn't actually print the value.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! This is a nice first answer.

Answer (score 5):

### Common Lisp, 27 bytes

*Tested on SBCL and ECL. For a portable approach, one should use [trivial-features](https://github.com/trivial-features/trivial-features/blob/master/SPEC.md).*

```
(lambda()'L #+big-endian'B)
```

The `#+` notation is a [read-time condition](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/01_ebaa.htm), that *reads* the next form only if the conditional expression evaluates to true. Here the condition is the whole `#+big-endian` text which means that the test is satisfied if the `:big-endian` keyword belongs to the [`*FEATURES*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_featur.htm) list (a list which contains among other things platform-specific information). The following expression is `'B`, which is either read or skipped according to the outcome of the test. 
If your platform is big-endian and you write the above form in the REPL, it is exactly as if you wrote the following:

```
CL-USER>(lambda()'L 'B)
```

<sup>(NB.`CL-USER>` is the prompt)</sup>

A function's body is an implicit [`PROGN`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_progn.htm), meaning that only the evaluation of the last expression is returned. So the above actually returns symbol ̀`B`.
If however the read-time condition evaluates to false, the form reads as if you wrote:

```
CL-USER>(lambda()'L)
```

... which simply returns symbol `L`.

Comment: Snippets are not allowed; write full programs or functions instead.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Updated, thanks

Comment: Note: Snippets are only allowed if explicitly permitted by the OP.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Could you provide a reference for this? There are other REPL answers over here and/or shell snippets and this [meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7842/903) would suggest that REPL answers could be ok by default. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

## C, 34 bytes

This assumes ASCII character encoding

```
main(a){putchar(66+10**(char*)a);}
```

Call without argument.

Explanation:

On call, `a` will be 1. `*(char*)a` accesses the first byte of `a`, which on little-endian platforms will be 1, on big-endian platforms will be 0.

On big-endian platforms, this code will therefore pass 66 + 10*0 = 66 to `putchar`. 66 is the ASCII code for `B`. On little-endian platforms, it will pass 66 + 10*1 = 76, which is the ASCII code for `L`.

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, <s>24</s> 19 bytes

```
()->ntoh(5)>>55+'B'
```

This is an anonymous function that takes no input and returns a `Char`. To call it, assign it to a variable. It assumes that integers are 64-bit.

The `ntoh` function converts the endianness of the value passed to it from network byte order (big endian) to that used by the host computer. On big endian machines, `ntoh` is the identity function since there's no conversion to be done. On little endian machines, the bytes are swapped, so `ntoh(5) == 360287970189639680`. Which is also, perhaps more readably, equal to: `0000010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` in binary.

If we right bit shift the result of `ntoh(5)` by 55, we'll get 0 on big endian machines and 10 on little endian machines. Adding that to the character constant `'B'`, we'll get `'B'` or `'L'` for big or little endian machines, respectively.

Saved 5 bytes thanks to FryAmTheEggman and Dennis!

Comment: For 32 bit you would have to change 55 to 23 (also the 5 in the 16 bit one should have been 7, my mistake). I think Dennis meant something like: `()->ntoh(5)>>55+'B'`?

Comment: `f()='L'-ntoh(10)%16` and `f()='L'-ntoh(10)&10` should work on all platforms.

Answer (score 5):

### ARMv6 and later: 20 bytes machine code

```
0xE10F1000 : MRS   r0,CPSR        ; read current status register
0xE3110C02 : TST   r0,#1<<9       ; set Z flag if bit 9 set
0x03A0004C : MOVEQ r0,#'L'        ; return 'L' if Z clear
0x13A00042 : MOVNE r0,#'B'        ; return 'B' if Z set
0xEBxxxxxx : BL    putchar        ; print it (relative branch)
```

Untested, as I don't have a suitable machine to hand.  Bit 9 of the CPSR gives the current load/store endianness.

Comment: You can use a return from the function (`BX lr`, is it?) instead of `putchar`, because `r0` is the proper register for returned result.

Comment: Indeed, that (actually MOV pc,lr) was in one of my previous edits.  However this fulfills the specification to _print_ the letter, not just return it.

Comment: I may be reading the reference wrong, but I think this can be done in the "thumb 2" instruction encoding.  This would mean the first instruction remained 32 bits ("encoding T1" on page F7-2720 of the ARM v8 reference manual, which would make it 0xF3EF_8000); the second is also 32 bits (encoding the operand is a bit bizarre, but can be done with "i:imm3" set to 0010 and "imm8" to 00000010, which gives an overall instruction of 0xF010_2F02). Before the third instruction, we need to insert "ITE EQ" (0xBF0C) to control the conditions on the next two MOV instructions, which become 0x204C and ...

Comment: ... 0x2042 (saving 2 bytes overall).  Then the final BL instruction is a little difficult to represent because the bits of the address which we don't know end up scattered among the bits of the instruction we do know, but it is also a 32-bit encoding, so the result would be 18 bytes total (F3 EF 80 00 F0 10 2F 02 BF 0C 20 4C 20 42 F? ?? ?? ??).  I believe this changes the architecture to ARMv8 and later, although it may work in ARMv7(?).

Answer (score 4):

## Perl 5, 21 + 1 = 22 bytes

Run with `perl -E`.

```pl
say ord pack(S,1)?L:B
```

Tested on amd64 (little-endian) and mips (big-endian).

Comment: Is the `-E` flag really necessary in the byte count? You can just say you use Perl 5.10 (since the `say`command is available in this version)

Comment: @PaulPicard No, the `say` command is not available in Perl 5.10 without `-E`.

Comment: Hmm, when I put `use 5.10.0;` it works... Or maybe I missed something.

Comment: @PaulPicard But `use 5.10.0;` is many more bytes!

Comment: Yeah but my point was if we assume that it's Perl 5.10, then there is no need for the `-E`switch or the `use` statement :p

Comment: @PaulPicard Your point is wrong. Perl 5.10 requires the `-E` switch or the `use` statement for `say`.

Comment: `-E` is "free" on PPCG. No need to add anything.

Comment: (however `-n` and `-p` are not)

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>28</s> 23 bytes

```
substr(.Platform$endian,1,1)
```

`.Platform$endian` returns `big` if run on big endian and `little` if on little. Here, using `substr`, it returns the first letter of the output, so either `b` or `l`.

As `endian` is the only object starting with an `e` contained in object `.Platform` we can reduce it thanks to partial matching to the following 23 bytes code:

```
substr(.Platform$e,1,1)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Clojure, <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```
#(nth(str(java.nio.ByteOrder/nativeOrder))0)
```

This is a function that uses the Java builtin to get the endianness of the machine. Then get the string representation of it which will be either `"LITTLE_ENDIAN"` or `"BIG_ENDIAN"` and take the first character of whichever string is chosen and return that.

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @[cliffroot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53197/cliffroot).

Comment: What is clojure really, is it lisp or java?

Comment: @LeakyNun Maybe a practical LISP that works with Java? It's hard to say.

Comment: `#(nth(str(java.nio.ByteOrder/nativeOrder))0)` is 2 bytes shorter

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <del>31</del>30 chars.

```
puts [1].pack("s")>"\01"??L:?B
```

Hmm, must be a better way. Count 5 characters less if the char need not to be output as I think other solutions omit printing. i.e. remove the "puts " part if you don't want anything printed.

Comment: If I remember correctly, after Ruby 1.9, you can use `?L` and `?B` in place of  `puts :L` and `puts "B"`

Comment: I think `puts [76,66].pack("s")[0]` will work.

Comment: @Sherlock9, thanks, one char less.
@WayneConrad, Perhaps add your answer, I don't have a big endian machine at hand to test but on little endian it works. But changing like this does not work: `puts [76,66].pack("s>")[0]`. That means it is possible to not be working on big endian for some reason I don't understand well. But this one seems to work (derived from your solution) `puts [19522].pack("s>")[0]`. WDYT? I wonder if I can find some place to evaluate on big endian.

Comment: Alas, I also lack a big-endian machine to test on.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash (and other unix shells), 32 (33) bytes

First and second attempt:

```
case `echo|od` in *5*)echo B;;*)echo L;;esac # portable
[[ `echo|od` =~ 5 ]]&&echo B||echo L         # non-portable
```

Thanks to Dennis, shorter version:

```
od<<<a|grep -q 5&&echo L||echo B  # non-portable
echo|od|grep -q 5&&echo B||echo L # portable
```

The `echo` utility outputs a newline, with hex value `0A`, and no other output. For `<<<a` it is `61 0A`.

The `od` utility, by default, interprets the input as two-byte words, zero-padded if the number of bytes is odd, and converts to octal. This results in the output of echo being interpred as `0A 00`, which is converted to `005000` as big-endian or `000012` in little-endian. `61 0A` becomes `005141` in little-endian and `060412` in big-endian. The full output of od also includes address and size data meaning we cannot use `0`, `1`, or `2` for the test.

The command is well-defined to expose the system's endianness. From [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/od.html):

> The byte order used when interpreting numeric values is implementation-defined, but shall correspond to the order in which a constant of the corresponding type is stored in memory on the system.

### Compatibility notes

I am not certain if putting `echo|od` in backquotes with no double quotes around them [which results in a three-word argument to `case`] is supported on all systems. I am not certain if all systems support shell scripts with no terminating newline. I am mostly certain but not 100% of the behavior of od with adding the padding byte on big-endian systems. If needed, `echo a` can be used for the portable versions. All of the scripts work in bash, ksh, and zsh, and the portable ones work in dash.

Comment: None of the changes are necessary; just put one shell it works in in the language headet and you're set.

Comment: @Dennis I like doing that kind of analysis... though it's more fun if I _do_ find something non-standard that gets a shorter answer in bash or zsh than the others. Maybe I'll see what can be done with `[[`

Comment: Nothing wrong with the analysis. The last paragraph just sounded like you were uncertain if a shell-specific answer is valid... `od<<<a|grep -q 5&&echo L||echo B` should work in Bash and others.

Comment: I tested it in a big-endian VM, and `echo|od` prints `0000000\n005000\n0000001` as you expected.

Comment: @user17752 Because endianness doesn't affect the output of `od -a`.

Answer (score 3):

### PHP, 16 bytes

```php
<?=pack(S,14)^B;
```

This uses two tricks not used in the two existing PHP answers:

1. The value passed to pack() or unpack() can be anything, not just 0 or 1.
2. The bitwise XOR operator (`^`) works on strings, and the result is only as long as the shorter string, avoiding the need for a string indexing or ternary operator.

Answer (score 2):

## Node, 42 bytes

```
n=>require('os').endianness()[0]
```

Pro: there's a builtin. Con: property names are very long

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 44 bytes

```
[char](66+10*[BitConverter]::IsLittleEndian)
```

Character 66 is `B`, and 10 characters later is number 76, `L`. A Boolean value of "true" becomes `1` when cast to a number. `BitConverter` is a standard .NET class.

Answer (score 2):

### Bash, 27 bytes

```
iconv -tucs2<<<䉌|head -c1
```

`䉌` ([U+424C](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=424C)) is encoded as three UTF-8 bytes: `E4 89 8C`.

It is assumed that `iconv` uses the function from glibc and that a UTF-8 locale is used.

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, <s>35</s> 28 bytes

```rkt
(if(system-big-endian?)'B'L)
```

`'B` or `'L` respectively. Let me know if this is not specific enough :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 42 bytes

```
{(""+java.nio.ByteOrder.nativeOrder())[0]}
```

Pretty straightforward. Uses "native" Java API. This is a lambda of `() -> Char` type.

String templates don't help much, unfortunately (still 42 bytes):

```
{"${java.nio.ByteOrder.nativeOrder()}"[0]}
```

Function approach (48 bytes):

```
fun e()=(""+java.nio.ByteOrder.nativeOrder())[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 22 bytes

```php
<?=ord(pack(S,1))?L:B;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell (using GHC-only size-restricted numeric types), 75 bytes

```
import Unsafe.Coerce
import GHC.Int
f="BL"!!fromEnum(unsafeCoerce 1::Int8)
```

(not tested on a big-endian architecture, but it seems like it *ought* to work!)

Answer (score 1):

### K,  15 bytes

```
    ("bl")@*6h$-8!`
    ,"l"
```

Explanation;

```
    From right to left;
    -8!`       /serialises the back tick and returns (0x010000000a000000f500)
    6h$-8!`    /This casts the result to `int which is type 6h(could have used `int$-8!`) - the result is (1 0 0 0 10 0 0 0 245 0i)
    *6h$-8!`   /* means first, we take the first item which is 1. Since it will be either 1 or 0, we can use it to index (@) into the two element list on the left i.e. ("bl")1 returns "l" and ("bl")0 returns b
```

Answer (score 1):

## GNU Utils, 35 bytes

```
lscpu|grep -o ':.*n'|grep -Eo 'L|B'
```

*Tested on `Linux kali 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux`, but I'm pretty sure the output should be fairly standard on most GNU/Linux distros.*

Answer (score 0):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>28</s> <s>19</s> <s>16</s> 15 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Both solutions below require `⎕IO←0`, which is default on many systems.

In cooperation with my [CTO](http://www.dyalog.com/meet-team-dyalog.htm#Jay):

```
'BL'⊃⍨⊃11⎕DR'⊢'
```

`11⎕DR'⊢'` interpret the character as 1 bit Boolean
  {0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0} on big-endian systems
  {1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0} on little-endian systems

`⊃` pick the first number, i.e. 0 on big endian systems, and 1 on little-endian systems

`'BL'⊃⍨` use that to pick from the string

<sup>This one is a bit interesting, as it requires storing in the "Classic" character set to be only 15 bytes, but must be executed in the "Unicode" interpreter to get a two byte representation. However, this is not a contradiction as the Unicode interpreter can load Classic workspaces.</sup>

---

Old solution:

```
'LB'⊃⍨'E'⎕FPROPS⎕D⎕FCREATE 0
```

`⎕D⎕FCREATE 0` create an APL component file with the name `0123456789`
`'E'⎕FPROPS` query endian-ness (`0`=little, `1`=big)
`'LB'⊃⍨` pick from the string

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
($cpuEndian)[0].echo
```

Takes the `cpuEndian` builtin (either `littleEndian` or `bigEndian` depending on the target CPU), stringifies it with `$`, takes its 0th character (`l` or `b` depending on the target CPU), and uses Nim's [uniform function call syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax) to `echo` the result.

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 151 Bytes

```vba
Type x
q As Long
End Type
Type z
w As Integer
End Type
Sub q()
Dim i As x, y As z
y.w=1
LSet i=y
Debug.? IIf(i.q=1,"L","B")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Lua, 31 bytes

```
print(("H"):pack(19522):sub(2))
```

Lua 5.3 is required.

Answer (score 0):

## C# <strike>50</strike> 49 bytes

Works, but has to be marked as unsafe

```
char i(){var a=0x0001;return*(byte*)&a>0?'L':'B';}
```

Updated:

```
unsafe char i(){int a=1;return"BL"[*(byte*)&a];}
```

Comment: You can use a classic trick since this is really producing 0 or 1, and index into a string to get the character `"BL"[...]`. Given it has to be run in an unsafe context, it should probably start with "unsafe char", and the compiler flag might need to be counted (I think it would be 1 byte, I can't remember the rules on that)... I should think you don't need any of the "0x000" stuff, "int a=1" ought to do fine.

Comment: @VisualMelon you're right, `unsafe char i(){int a=1;return"BL"[*(byte*)&a];}` is ok?

Comment: Yeah, that looks good (well remembered removing the space after the return, easy to miss that one)

Answer (score 0):

### Tcl, 46 bytes

```
puts [string index $tcl_platform(byteOrder) 0]
```

(Nothing fancy. Just in case someone wants to know how to do it in Tcl.)